# AngularJS CORS error when passing post params to WCF service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wcf, cors

Have a WCF webservice running locally ,POST API looks like this `

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        public string AssignLoopToLocations(int LoopID, int[] LocationIDs)
        {
            string strFileName = "AssignLoopToLocations_respone.xml";
            string strResult = GetFileData(strFileName);
            return strResult;
        }
```

I have added following lines in Web.config of service in system.webserver tag for CORS `

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>`
```

`

My angular side API call looks this `

```
factory.assignLocationsToLoop = function ( LoopID,locationList ) {
        var data = {
            LoopID : LoopID, LocationIDs : locationList
        } 
        return $http.post(mediaServicePath + "AssignLoopToLocations", data);
```

`
 [image: Chrome network debugger]

I am getting this error only when accessing api that has params .When runnin g the same API call in Postman able to get the reponse.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you debug the WCF service? Chances are that the message is arriving but ANY other server error will cause a 405 because the OPTIONS preflight request has not been answered. Another little comment: remove 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', from the $http.post call, that header should not be sent by the client; it's a server matter

Comment: Able to get response from web service api when called through postman

Comment: Not an expert with Postman, but as it is not a browser, the OPTIONS request is probably not being sent, so you're not having CORS issues on it. The problem is between the browser and the server

Comment: Yes absolutely correct , the options is not handled correctly on the server end .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the solution has appeared by making a Global.cs file in WCF service as follows `

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

`
All this with no  httpProtocol code mentioned in the above Web.config.